# Why is GCC 11 compiler producing weird output when optimization is enabled?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, optimization, casting

Please take a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t run = 1;

    /* Define variable of interest and set to random value */
    uint32_t dwTime = 0xdeadc0de;

    /* Define uint16_t pointer */
    uint16_t* tmpU16;
    /* Assign least 16 bits from dwTime to tmpU16 by downcasting from uint32_t to uint16_t */
    tmpU16 = (uint16_t*)&dwTime;

    /* Print content of tmpU16 */
    fprintf(stderr, "TEST: %04x\n", *tmpU16); /* Will print "TEST: c0de" here */

    /* This loop will run exactly once */
    while (run)
    {
        /* Print content of tmpU16 AGAIN (content of tmpU16 should not have changed here!) */
        /* Will print "TEST: 0000" here when optimization is enabled */
        /* Will print "TEST: c0de" here when optimization is disabled */
        fprintf(stderr, "TEST: %04x\n", *tmpU16);

        /* Increment tmpU16 pointer by 1 (yes, this does not make sense but it should not do any harm
        either, unless something gets written to its address AFTER incrementing */
        tmpU16++;
        run--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this code with GCC 11 and optimization enabled (for example `-O2`) it will produce following output:

```
TEST: c0de
TEST: 0000
```

When this code is compiled without optimization (`-O0`) it will produce:

```
TEST: c0de
TEST: c0de
```

I assumed after the first `fprintf` is executed, the next `fprintf` inside the while loop will be executed immediately. In between these two `fprintf`s nothing should happen, hence content of `tmpU16` stay unchanged.

However, when I comment out the `tmpU16++` pointer incrementation, it produces correct output with optimization.

Why is this, what's happening here?

Comment: You're invoking undefined behaviour, so anything can happen. Without optimization, it's acting in a "dumb" way, literally doing what you're telling it to do. With optimizations, the compiler could figure out the value of `*tmpU16` to be more efficient, but what you're telling it is illegal, so it's doing whatever it "wants", and using the value 0.

Comment: Note that the comments are wrong: no bits of the number are assigned anywhere when you make a pointer point somewhere. There’s no downcasting here.

Comment: @ThomasJager Can you pinpoint UB here? I only see strict aliasing violation, which is *usually* not causing visible effects (well, maybe it does here....)

Comment: With `-O2 -fno-strict-aliasing` it gives the output OP expected, so the aliasing violation seems to be the culprit here. https://godbolt.org/z/ahhG5e71W

Comment: @ThomasJager “Assign at least 16 bits from dwTime to tmpU16 by downcasting…” sounds fine?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The strict aliasing violation is the problem.

Comment: @ThomasJager Oh, yes. Should’ve been more clear about that, sorry

Comment: Turning on warnings (with `-O2`) in GCC tells me that `warning: 'dwTime' is used uninitialized`, but it very clearly is initialized. This is a hint at the strict aliasing violation. Clang on the other hand does what you seem to want (printing one of the words of `dwTime`), without emitting a warning, though this is still UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
tmpU16 = (uint16_t*)&dwTime;
```

You're committing a strict aliasing violation by treating an object of one type as if it were another incompatible type.

Section 6.5p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) lists the conditions in which aliasing may occur:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:<sup>88)</sup>
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.
>
> ---
>
> 88 ) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased

Using a pointer to a `uint16_t` to access a `uint32_t` does not fall under any of these categories.  Such a violation triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With gcc in particular, enforcement of strict aliasing rules isn't enabled unless you either use `-O2` or greater, or explicitly use `-fstrict-aliasing`.  By enforcing this rule, the compiler is able to make optimizations it wouldn't be able to make otherwise.